# Remove non-select text in Python Script

Tags: python

I got huge amount of text data to deal with(through Orange), but need to clean it up somehow. Which means I need to remove all useless word for every line. Here is the code I put in Python Script(In Orange).

```
for i in range(1):
    print in_data[i]
```

The data is one word per column.

```
Running script:
['1', 'NSW', 'Worst service ever', '0', 'I've', 'experi', 'drop', 'calls', 'late',    'voicemail', 'messages', 'poor', 'batteri', 'life', 'and', 'bad', '3G', 'coverage.', 'Complain', 'to', 'the', 'call', 'centr', 'doe', 'noth', 'and', 'thei', 'refus', 'to', 'replac', 'my', 'phone', 'or', 'let', 'me', 'out', 'of', 'the', 'contract', 'I', 'just', 'signed.', 'Thei', 'deni', 'there', 'is', 'ani', 'Dropped calls']
```

I am planning to remove all useless word. For example, I wanna keep only "Dropped calls","Complain"  and remove all the rest. Base on this large amount of data. I need to use for loop to clean each line. But what method can keep the word I want and remove all the rest?

Comment: You can use `if` instruction. Or `filter()`. Or list comprehension. Or dozen other techniques. This is such a basic question, that it doesn't really fit in here. Please find a book about programming and learn some basic concepts, like branching your program.

Comment: if statement very good. else also canna usa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order of words is not important, you could define a set of useful words and take a set intersection with the list of all words per line.

```
useful_words = set(['Complain', 'Dropped calls', 'lolcat'])
for i in range(x):
    filtered_words = useful_words.intersection(set(in_data[i]))
    print filtered_words
```

(This is just a rough draft, which needs some form of text preprocessing and normalizations, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

The following should be an efficient solution both in time and space

```
# generator to yield every word which is in the set to keep
def filter_gen(words, words_to_keep):
    for word in words:
        if word in words_to_keep:
            yield word

words_to_keep = set(( "Bb", "Dd"))

words = [ "Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd" ]
res = [ word for word in filter_gen(words, words_to_keep) ]

>>> res
['Bb', 'Dd']
```